# How to customize the user login form?

Tags: 8, forms, theming

I'm trying to customize user login form in `/user/login` page and I want to use a `hook_form_alter` function to add some awesome style and placeholder to each of user login form fields and remove or hide: 
"Enter your *admin* username" and "Enter the password that accompanies your username" description expressions under each of theme.
To resolve this issue I added something like below code to my **ThemeName.theme**:

```
function ThemeName_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ( $form['#form_id'] == 'user_login_form' ) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'button glow button-primary expanded';
    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder']['name'] = t('User name');
    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder']['password'] = t('Password');
  }
}
```

I try out many different ways but I can't get any result.
in finally I want to achieve something like below image:
[image]

I read this pages but seems none work in Drupal 8:
[How to modify the fields of user registration form and user login form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86659/how-to-modify-the-fields-of-user-registration-form-and-user-login-form)
[Modifying the default user registration page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30279/modifying-the-default-user-registration-page)
[Customize user login block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188694/customize-user-login-block)

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that `user-login-form` should be `user_login_form` in your function.

Comment: Why not just do it with CSS? `.user-login-form .description { display: none; }`

Comment: The actual strings that you are trying to remove are in UserLoginForm.php - it will be helpful for you to read that code to see how the form is constructed.

Comment: I presume you can add a placeholder attribute when doing the `form_alter()` stuff

Comment: See what Jeff Burnz has said in the answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add placeholders in hook_form_alter().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function ThemeName_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_form' ) {
    // Add placeholders.
    $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('User name');
    $form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Password');
  }
}
```

Use the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) functions to print out the form using kint, this way you can visibly see the entire structure of the $form array.

Comment: It seems that `User Name` should be `Username` or `User name` to t() function work's correctly.

Comment: The problem is not of the function, but of the string within the function, I used what you used because I have to assume you may rely on that string in your translations.

Answer (score 2):

**SimpleLogin**

https://www.drupal.org/project/simplelogin

It is a simple module for Customize Drupal Login, Password and Register pages with Background images.

Administrators can provide the ability to allow users to attach their own background images/ own background color to user login, password, registration pages. Better features including customize background color, image settings.

Features:
Clean & Sleek Design,
Customize background color, link color, submit button color,
Customize image settings,
Background image Opacity,
Remove unwanted Css files from simplelogin pages,
Login pages wrapper width,
Mobile responsive,