# Add /usr/login welcome screen

Tags: 8

Drupal8 newbie here (using better login and system caching is on),

I wanted to just add a php page before the login page that says something like :

```
"Please follow the rules of our site, click accept button to agree and login in:"

                                   [Accept Button]
```

After pressing the button it forwards you to the normal /user/login page. Any tips would be great, it seems harder than it should be, we really don't want to use JQuery/JS.

Comment: Does it have to be a unique page? Just to get the ball rolling, you could alter the login form via `HOOK_form_alter()`. This would allow you to add a field item that asks the user to accept the user agreement. You could also set the other fields to show conditionally only if the user accepts. This would most likely be a much quicker path to take...

Comment: A related question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211509/how-to-customize-the-user-login-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom module:
Example:

1. MODULE_NAME(mydata)
2. creat routing file. (mydata.routing.yml):

   ```
        mydata.redirect_form:
          path: '/user/redirect'
          defaults:
            _form: '\Drupal\mydata\Form\RedirectForm'
            _title: 'Redirect User'
          requirements:
            _permission: 'access content'
   ```
3. Create .module file (mydata.module):

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
   use Drupal\Core\Url;

   function mydata_preprocess_page(&$var){
       if(empty($_SESSION['terms_accepted']) || $_SESSION['terms_accepted'] != 'ok'){
           if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == "user.login"){
               $path = Url::fromRoute('mydata.redirect_form', [], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
               $response = new RedirectResponse($path);
               return $response->send();

           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create file in module folder src/Form/RedirectForm.php:

   ```
   namespace Drupal\mydata\Form;

   use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
   use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
   use Drupal\Core\Url;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

   class RedirectForm extends FormBase {

       public function getFormId() {
           return 'redirect_form';
       }

       public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
           if(!empty(@$_SESSION['terms_accepted']) || @$_SESSION['terms_accepted'] == 'ok'){
               $path = Url::fromRoute('user.login', [], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
               $response = new RedirectResponse($path);
               return $response->send();
           }

           $form['test'] = [
               '#type' => 'item',
               '#markup' => t('Please Follow the rule of our site,click accept button to agree and login-in: '),
           ];

           $form['submit'] = [
               '#type' => 'submit',
               '#value' => 'Accept',
           ];

           return $form;

         }

       public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
           $_SESSION['terms_accepted'] = 'ok';
           if($_SESSION['terms_accepted']){
               $form_state->setRedirect('user.login');
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I am getting a route error etc when I try this

Comment: you need to create correct routing format otherwise it will generate error ,you  need to care about spacing and no tabs ,copy the routing file from here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api ,and make changes according to above

Comment: above example is 100% tested its working in my site.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, my yml didn't fix correctly when I told PHP Storm to reformat it.  Also, I did a couple of things to get it to work with the caching and to ask for the the message every time using a session time stamp. I set a session time stamp of time()+4 seconds and if you click login within 4 seconds you don't see the message,  > 4 seconds it asks agin. I noticed before that it would never ask unless you logged out and it destroyed the session (I believe). I can show you code I created if you wanted. Again, thanks you were a huge help to me understanding this!

Comment: I think @ were in there to hide unset vars : !empty(@$_SESSION['terms_accepted']) || @$_SESSION['terms_accepted'] == 'ok' so I changed it to !empty(xxx) && xxx = "ok" .

Comment: yes you can post your answer here ,it might be helpfull for others too..

Comment: ok cool thanks again, I really appreciate that you worked with me to fix that issue.

Comment: I have one last problem, and have not found a solution. When better login is installed it ignores my module, I tried adding a weight to the module but it didn't help, do you have any advice ?